# How to Import on InventItemLocation table?

Tags: import, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, aif

I know some classes **AIF** to import in to *standard Table* , look like : InventItem_InventTable ; VendVendTable_VendTable , etc...

I have to import in to InventTable, and, I wanto to insert too in the **InventItemLocation** table.

When I launch the :

```
entityKeyList = InventItemService::construct().create(InventItemDocument);
```

happens the InventItemLocation automatic population.

Is there other AIF classes for to import and populate the `InventItemLocation`?

I would decide to insert specific fields (not related to inventTable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot test it right now, but I would give the `AxInventItemLocation` class ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/axinventitemlocation.aspx)) a try.
Something like this:

```
AxInventItemLocation axInventItemLocation;

axInventItemLocation = AxInventItemLocation::construct();

axInventItemLocation.parmItemId(someItemId);
axInventItemLocation.parmInventDimId(aInventDimId);

axInventItemLocation.save();
```